# React Native + WebRTC TypeError: Undefined is not and Object(Evaluating: 'data.type')

Tags: node.js, react-native, sockets, webrtc, signaling

I've been trying to learn WebRTC with React Native, so I've been working on this video call project. I thought I had it all figured out until this came up.

First of all, this is my React Native Code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from 'react-native-paper';
import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';

import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';

import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';

import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';

export default function CallScreen({navigation, ...props}) {
  let name;
  let connectedUser;
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
  const [socketActive, setSocketActive] = useState(false);
  const [calling, setCalling] = useState(false);
  // Video Scrs
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState({toURL: () => null});
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState({toURL: () => null});
  const [conn, setConn] = useState(new WebSocket('ws://:4443/'));
  const [yourConn, setYourConn] = useState(
    new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',  
        }, {
          urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',    
        }, {
          urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',    
        }, {
          username: "",
          credential: "",
          urls: 'turn::3478',
        }, {
          username: "",
          credential: "",
          urls: 'stun::3478',
        }
      ],
    }),
  );

  const [offer, setOffer] = useState(null);

  const [callToUsername, setCallToUsername] = useState(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(id => {
        console.log(id);
        if (id) {
          setUserId(id);
        } else {
          setUserId('');
          navigation.push('Login');
        }
      });
    }, [userId]),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'Hola' + userId,
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button mode="text" onPress={onLogout} style={{paddingRight: 10}}>
          Salir
        </Button>
      ),
    });
  }, [userId]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (socketActive && userId.length > 0) {
      try {
        InCallManager.start({media: 'audio'});
        InCallManager.setForceSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('InApp Caller ---------------------->', err);
      }

      console.log(InCallManager);

      send({
        type: 'login',
        name: userId,
      });
    }
  }, [socketActive, userId]);

  const onLogin = () => {};

  useEffect(() => {

    conn.onopen = () => {
      console.log('Connected to the signaling server');
      setSocketActive(true);
    };
    conn.onmessage = msg => {
      let data;
      if (msg.data === 'Hello world') {
        data = {};
      } else {
        dcata = JSON.parse(msg.data);
        console.log('Data --------------------->', data);
        switch (data.type) {
          case 'login':
            console.log('Login');
            break;
          case 'offer':
            handleOffer(data.offer, data.name);
            console.log('Offer');
            break;
          case 'answer':
            handleAnswer(data.answer);
            console.log('Answer');
            break;
          case 'candidate':
            handleCandidate(data.candidate);
            console.log('Candidate');
            break;
          case 'leave':
            handleLeave();
            console.log('Leave');
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    };
    conn.onerror = function(err) {
      console.log('Got error', err);
    };

    let isFront = false;
    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(sourceInfos => {
      let videoSourceId;
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }
      mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              minWidth: 500, 
              minHeight: 300,
              minFrameRate: 30,
            },
            facingMode: isFront ? 'user' : 'environment',
            optional: videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [],
          },
        })
        .then(stream => {
          setLocalStream(stream);

          yourConn.addStream(stream);
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
    });

    yourConn.onaddstream = event => {
      console.log('On Add Stream', event);
      setRemoteStream(event.stream);
    };

    yourConn.onicecandidate = event => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        send({
          type: 'candidate',
          candidate: event.candidate,
        });
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const send = message => {
    if (connectedUser) {
      message.name = connectedUser;
      console.log('Connected iser in end----------', message);
    }

    conn.send(JSON.stringify(message));
  };

  const onCall = () => {
    setCalling(true);

    connectedUser = callToUsername;
    console.log('Caling to', callToUsername);


    yourConn.createOffer().then(offer => {
      yourConn.setLocalDescription(offer).then(() => {
        console.log('Sending Ofer');
        console.log(offer);
        send({
          type: 'offer',
          offer: offer,
        });
      });
    });
  };

  const handleOffer = async (offer, name) => {
    console.log(name + ' is calling you.');

    console.log('Accepting Call===========>', offer);
    connectedUser = name;

    try {
      await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

      const answer = await yourConn.createAnswer();

      await yourConn.setLocalDescription(answer);
      send({
        type: 'answer',
        answer: answer,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Offerr Error', err);
    }
  };

  const handleAnswer = answer => {
    yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
  };

  const handleCandidate = candidate => {
    setCalling(false);
    console.log('Candidate ----------------->', candidate);
    yourConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
  };

  const hangUp = () => {
    send({
      type: 'leave',
    });

    handleLeave();
  };

  const handleLeave = () => {
    connectedUser = null;
    setRemoteStream({toURL: () => null});

    yourConn.close();

  };

  const onLogout = () => {

    AsyncStorage.removeItem('userId').then(res => {
      navigation.push('Login');
    });
  };

  const acceptCall = async () => {
    console.log('Accepting Call===========>', offer);
    connectedUser = offer.name;

    try {
      await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

      const answer = await yourConn.createAnswer();

      await yourConn.setLocalDescription(answer);

      send({
        type: 'answer',
        answer: answer,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Offerr Error', err);
    }
  };
  const rejectCall = async () => {
    send({
      type: 'leave',
    });
    ``;
    setOffer(null);

    handleLeave();
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <View style={styles.inputField}>
        <TextInput
          label="Ingresa el ID del familiar"
          mode="outlined"
          style={{marginBottom: 7}}
          onChangeText={text => setCallToUsername(text)}
        />
        <Button
          mode="contained"
          onPress={onCall}
          loading={calling}
          //   style={styles.btn}
          contentStyle={styles.btnContent}
          disabled={!(socketActive && userId.length > 0)}>
          Llamar
        </Button>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
        <View style={[styles.videos, styles.localVideos]}>
          <Text>Tu video</Text>
          <RTCView streamURL={localStream.toURL()} style={styles.localVideo} />
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.videos, styles.remoteVideos]}>
          <Text>Video del familiar</Text>
          <RTCView
            streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()}
            style={styles.remoteVideo}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  inputField: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  videoContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    minHeight: 450,
  },
  videos: {
    width: '100%',
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden',

    borderRadius: 6,
  },
  localVideos: {
    height: 100,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  remoteVideos: {
    height: 400,
  },
  localVideo: {
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
  remoteVideo: {
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

At this point is worth to mention that my STUN/TURN server works perfectly, and this is my signaling socket

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 4443}); 
var users = {};

wss.on('connection', function(connection) {

   console.log('User connected');

   //when server gets a message from a connected user
   connection.on('message', function(message) { 

      var data; 
      //accepting only JSON messages 
      try {
         data = JSON.parse(message); 
      } catch (e) { 
         console.log('Invalid JSON'); 
         data = {}; 
      } 

      //switching type of the user message 
      switch (data.type) { 
         //when a user tries to login 

         case 'login': 
            console.log('User logged', data.name); 

            //if anyone is logged in with this username then refuse 
            if(users[data.name]) { 
               sendTo(connection, { 
                  type: 'login', 
                  success: false 
               }); 
            } else { 
               //save user connection on the server 
               users[data.name] = connection; 
               connection.name = data.name; 

               sendTo(connection, { 
                  type: 'login', 
                  success: true 
               }); 
            } 

            break; 

         case 'offer': 
            //for ex. UserA wants to call UserB 
            console.log('Sending offer to: ', data.offer, data.name); 

            //if UserB exists then send him offer details 
            var conn = users[data.name];

            if(conn != null) { 
               //setting that UserA connected with UserB 
               connection.otherName = data.name; 

               sendTo(conn, { 
                  type: 'offer', 
                  offer: data.offer, 
                  name: connection.name 
               }); 
            } 

            break;  

         case 'answer': 
            console.log('Sending answer to: ', data.answer); 
            //for ex. UserB answers UserA 
            var conn = users[data.answer]; 

            if(conn != null) { 
               connection.otherName = data.name; 
               sendTo(conn, { 
                  type: 'answer', 
                  answer: data.answer 
               }); 
            } 

            break;  

         case 'candidate': 
            console.log("Sending candidate to:",data.name); 
            var conn = users[data.name];  

            if(conn != null) { 
               sendTo(conn, { 
                  type: 'candidate', 
                  candidate: data.candidate 
               });
            } 

            break;  

         case 'leave': 
            console.log('Disconnecting from', data.name); 
            var conn = users[data.name]; 
            conn.otherName = null; 

            //notify the other user so he can disconnect his peer connection 
            if(conn != null) { 
               sendTo(conn, { 
                  type: 'leave' 
               }); 
            }  

            break;  

         default: 
            sendTo(connection, { 
               type: 'error', 
               message: 'Command not found: ' + data.type 
            }); 

            break; 
      }  
   });  

   //when user exits, for example closes a browser window 
   //this may help if we are still in "offer","answer" or "candidate" state 
   connection.on('close', function() { 

      if(connection.name) { 
      delete users[connection.name]; 

         if(connection.otherName) { 
            console.log('Disconnecting from ', connection.otherName);
            var conn = users[connection.otherName]; 
            conn.otherName = null;  

            if(conn != null) { 
               sendTo(conn, { 
                  type: 'leave' 
               });
            }  
         } 
      } 
   });  

   connection.send('Hello world'); 

});  

function sendTo(connection, message) { 
   connection.send(JSON.stringify(message)); 
}
```

But here si where the problems begin.

When I use the App to login this is what the Socket shows.

```
User connected
User connected
User connected
User logged 1
User connected
User connected
User connected
User connected
User connected
```

But immediately, the app shows this.

[image: Red box error after socket connection]

And if I dismiss the error and try to Call another peer that is already conected, the error shows on the device I try to Call.

[image: Red box after call attempt]

The React Native cli, tells me the same as the error

```
Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Tue Jun 02 2020 10:34:26.400]  LOG      Running "webrtcApp" with {"rootTag":1}
[Tue Jun 02 2020 10:37:20.365]  LOG      Connected to the signaling server
[Tue Jun 02 2020 10:37:20.487]  LOG      1
[Tue Jun 02 2020 10:37:20.747]  LOG      {"audioUriMap": {"busytone": {"_BUNDLE_": null, "_DEFAULT_": null}, "ringback": {"_BUNDLE_": null, "_DEFAULT_": null}, "ringtone": {"_BUNDLE_": null, "_DEFAULT_": null}}, "cameraPermission": "granted", "checkCameraPermission": [Function bound checkCameraPermission], "checkRecordPermission": [Function bound checkRecordPermission], "recordPermission": "granted", "requestCameraPermission": [Function bound requestCameraPermission], "requestRecordPermission": [Function bound requestRecordPermission], "vibrate": false}
[Tue Jun 02 2020 10:37:20.914]  LOG      1
[Tue Jun 02 2020 10:37:20.933]  LOG      Data ---------------------> undefined
[Tue Jun 02 2020 10:37:52.746]  LOG      Data ---------------------> undefined
```

And here it is what the socket shows when I try to call another peer that is Connected.

```
Sending offer to:  {
  sdp: 'v=0\r\n' +
    'o=- 3903065942025360998 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\n' +
    's=-\r\n' +
    't=0 0\r\n' +
    'a=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\n' +
    'a=msid-semantic: WMS 4169861f-fa77-4c52-b0a7-da4673eb4512\r\n' +
    'm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\n' +
    'c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n' +
    'a=ice-ufrag:+CFh\r\n' +
    'a=ice-pwd:ccPSGw5U3fnoHysgp1bquCYJ\r\n' +
    'a=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\n' +
    'a=fingerprint:sha-256 2A:2B:C1:A4:1D:8C:B3:C3:B8:AA:6D:C2:36:71:F7:95:61:CC:54:E6:2D:79:C0:4D:A5:D4:E1:45:3D:00:BF:F4\r\n' +
    'a=setup:actpass\r\n' +
    'a=mid:audio\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:2 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\n' +
    'a=sendrecv\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-mux\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\n' +
    'a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:3496221613 cname:7efsTJMX4YNf740V\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:3496221613 msid:4169861f-fa77-4c52-b0a7-da4673eb4512 8c0eb0bb-a1ab-422a-a527-5d5bc73635b7\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:3496221613 mslabel:4169861f-fa77-4c52-b0a7-da4673eb4512\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:3496221613 label:8c0eb0bb-a1ab-422a-a527-5d5bc73635b7\r\n' +
    'm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127\r\n' +
    'c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n' +
    'a=ice-ufrag:+CFh\r\n' +
    'a=ice-pwd:ccPSGw5U3fnoHysgp1bquCYJ\r\n' +
    'a=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\n' +
    'a=fingerprint:sha-256 2A:2B:C1:A4:1D:8C:B3:C3:B8:AA:6D:C2:36:71:F7:95:61:CC:54:E6:2D:79:C0:4D:A5:D4:E1:45:3D:00:BF:F4\r\n' +
    'a=setup:actpass\r\n' +
    'a=mid:video\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:13 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:3 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:2 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:8 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07\r\n' +
    'a=extmap:9 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space\r\n' +
    'a=sendrecv\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-mux\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-rsize\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000\r\n' +
    'a=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\n' +
    'a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\n' +
    'a=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:100 red/90000\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000\r\n' +
    'a=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\n' +
    'a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc-group:FID 1093641884 443757454\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:1093641884 cname:7efsTJMX4YNf740V\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:1093641884 msid:4169861f-fa77-4c52-b0a7-da4673eb4512 47eb8496-acdf-48ae-a7bb-bb44e758b23e\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:1093641884 mslabel:4169861f-fa77-4c52-b0a7-da4673eb4512\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:1093641884 label:47eb8496-acdf-48ae-a7bb-bb44e758b23e\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:443757454 cname:7efsTJMX4YNf740V\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:443757454 msid:4169861f-fa77-4c52-b0a7-da4673eb4512 47eb8496-acdf-48ae-a7bb-bb44e758b23e\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:443757454 mslabel:4169861f-fa77-4c52-b0a7-da4673eb4512\r\n' +
    'a=ssrc:443757454 label:47eb8496-acdf-48ae-a7bb-bb44e758b23e\r\n',
  type: 'offer'
} 2
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:3362660723 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.232.2 51977 typ host generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 3 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 0,
  sdpMid: 'audio'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:1914131086 1 udp 2122187263 fec0::ff:fe44:5566 41727 typ host generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 4 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 0,
  sdpMid: 'audio'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:3362660723 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.232.2 46626 typ host generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 3 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 1,
  sdpMid: 'video'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:1914131086 1 udp 2122187263 fec0::ff:fe44:5566 39496 typ host generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 4 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 1,
  sdpMid: 'video'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 189.133.49.117 60389 typ srflx raddr 192.168.232.2 rport 51977 generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 3 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 0,
  sdpMid: 'audio'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:4231669940 1 udp 1685989631 2806:106e:a:f03d:7d79:9dd4:5653:7381 60393 typ srflx raddr fec0::ff:fe44:5566 rport 41727 generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 4 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 0,
  sdpMid: 'audio'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:4231669940 1 udp 1685989631 2806:106e:a:f03d:7d79:9dd4:5653:7381 60394 typ srflx raddr fec0::ff:fe44:5566 rport 39496 generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 4 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 1,
  sdpMid: 'video'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 189.133.49.117 60392 typ srflx raddr 192.168.232.2 rport 46626 generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 3 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 1,
  sdpMid: 'video'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:2108125103 1 udp 41885439 172.31.19.115 64788 typ relay raddr 189.133.49.117 rport 60392 generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 3 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 1,
  sdpMid: 'video'
}
Sending candidate to: {
  candidate: 'candidate:2108125103 1 udp 41885439 172.31.19.115 55279 typ relay raddr 189.133.49.117 rport 60389 generation 0 ufrag +CFh network-id 3 network-cost 10',
  sdpMLineIndex: 0,
  sdpMid: 'audio'
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong, but any help on what it is my problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in `onmessage` on React Native. rename `dcata` to `data`. upvote if you find the answer useful.

Comment: That was the error, I lost my glasses last week and I wouldn't've never found it. Thank You So Much.